# Why does my 'click' eventListener only start working after the first click?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener

I am fairly new to javascript and have a small problem with the addEventListener function. 
I am trying to build some buttons that look like they have been "pressed down" after you click on them. In general this works great, except for one thing:
the eventListener only works after the first click on the element has been done (this means it won't fire on the first, but the second click):

```
<div id="sidebar">
<p class="Lebenslauf" id="btn1" onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mOut(this)"><span>Studium</span></p>
<p class="Lebenslauf" id="btn2" onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mOut(this)"><span>Arbeit</span></p>
<p class="Lebenslauf" id="btn3" onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mOut(this)"><span>Freizeit</span></p>
<p class="Lebenslauf" id="btn4" onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mOut(this)"><span>Referenzen</span></p>
</div>
<script>
function addBtnListeners(){
for (var i=1;i<=4;i++){
    btn=document.getElementById("btn"+i);
    btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
        if(this.style.boxShadow=="0px 0px 15px"){
            this.style.boxShadow="0px 0px 0px";
        }else{
            this.style.boxShadow="0px 0px 15px";
        }
    },false);
}
}
addBtnListeners();
function mOver(obj){
    obj.style.backgroundColor="#F1F1F1";
}
function mOut(obj){
    obj.style.backgroundColor="#CCCCCC";
}
</script>
```

and the css:

```
.Lebenslauf{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    border-radius:100px;
    height:80%;
    width:10%;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 15px black;
    float:left;
    margin-right:1em;
    margin-left:1em;
    display:table;
}
```

I would appreciate any tips or hints on what might be the problem or what topics I should look into.

Best regards

Edit: inserting

```
btn.style.boxShadow="0px 0px 15px";
```

right before I add the eventListeners solves the problem!

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/btLr16z3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `style` property represents the *inline* style set on an element so `this.style.boxShadow` will initially be `""` because the style is coming from a stylesheet and not a style attribute.

The first click hits the `else` branch and explicitly sets the inline style to match the style that is cascaded from the stylesheet. The second click then matches the first part of the `if` statement.